# How to style DatePicker on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have date picker which I've tried to customize to a different style but to no avail.
I want to show a DatePicker and not a DatePickerDialog.

In the layout design tab on Android Studio, the DatePicker's background color is black and the text color is white.

However, the datePicker occupies space on the device screen but is not visible.
I've also tried to change the AppTheme.
The DatePicker code is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.AgeFragment">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:textColor="@color/titleBlack"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="When's your birthday?"
            android:textColor="@color/titleBlack"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="Your birthday won't be shown publicly"
            android:textColor="#7A7474"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/date_picker2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:calendarTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:background="@color/pinkBtnBackground"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date_picker2" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DatePickerStyle</item>

    </style>

    <style name="DatePickerStyle">
        <item name="android:calendarTextColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    </style>
```

The result is still the same. I've searched for answers but none provides a solution to this problem.
Any help or reference to a documentation that provide an explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and it shows Red Date Picker. What is the container layout of this date picker?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It addresses DatePicker inside of AlertDialog. The answer provided is  DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
 AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,this,year,month,day); but doesn't work for a normal date picker since I do not want to display a dialog.

Comment: Post the code with Constraint layout

Comment: kelvin, in the layout design tab it show a black color but when you run it on an Android device its not visible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220786/discussion-between-kelvin-and-andrew-chelix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `<item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>` from the style. It is messing with your current Layout

Comment: It works but I don't understand why you can set <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item> then override the background color of the DatePicker in the xml layout attributes since most of my app's background is white so setting white as the background color in the AppTheme is very convenient.

Comment: It is getting applied to the Date picker too, + fonts are white ! so it is there but  we can't see it.. First i thought you might have problems with the constaint layout but now looks like it is this white background that is causing problems